# How can I run a WordPress website with the same MySQL database into two different servers?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running a website on WordPress wherein daily 10K visitors coming. Now I would like to change the existing Theme and Server (Ubuntu 16.04 & LEMP). I have two points that make me confuse because I don't want to disturb visitors.

1. Can I make a live website on two servers with different IP at the same time?
   For ex., newly designed website access by IP (https://198.XXX.XXX.XXX)
   AND
   Old website can keep running on an existing server IP & Domain Name.
2. If any new article comes up or updated on existing website [old] then will it automatically apply (add) on new server website?

In short, how can I run WordPress based two websites with the same MySQL database into two different servers?

If that is possible, please guide me how.

Comment: keeping the two mysql schemas in sync is going to be a hassle. And really error-prone. I highly suggest you to prepare the new stack, put your site under maintenance and change the DNS. Put a 301 redirect on old ip towards the new host, go back online with your database still in one piece

Answer (score 0):

Open wp-config.php in your WordPress installation. find this `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` line and replace with `define('DB_HOST', 'https://198.XXX.XXX.XXX');` using your old database server's IP you will be now able to access your old server's database.

You also need to update site_url to access media files. or you can use  FeedWordpress plugin.

[Two WordPress sites sharing the same content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76020/two-wordpress-sites-sharing-the-same-content)

Comment: what about site url in wp_options table?

Comment: @ChinmayRajyaguru as you want to use a different server for a different website you need to update DB_HOST to.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time @hardik. Revision #2 [Edited Answer] is perfect for test purpose. I will test your detailed answer method into localhost and inform you.